# WooCommerce - Overwrite action hook

Tags: hooks, woocommerce-offtopic

Within the WooCommerce template file "content-product.php", I'm trying to overwrite the following action hook:

```
/**
* woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title hook
*
* @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );
```

To overwrite this hook, I have added the following to my functions.php file:

add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'change_product_title');

```
function change_product_title() {
    echo'<header class="entry-header"><h1 class="entry-title">'.get_the_title().'</h1></header>';
}
```

This only adds to the hook. How do I completly replace the hook with my own code? I have checked the WooCommerce documentation, but it doesn't give you a great deal to go on.

Comment: remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple to change the title in content-product.php, but you won't be able to do it with a hook. Near the top of the file, you should see this line:

```
Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php
```

All you have to do is copy the file to the above directory, replacing "yourtheme" with your theme's actual folder name, and make your desired edits to the new file.

**A little more background on hooks**

The title in the default content-product.php template file is outputted like this, which is defined in wc-template-functions.php if you search for woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() it echos the below title:

```
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
```

In order to change the title with a hook, you'd need to change the above line to this, but you can't do this without changing the wc-template-functions.php file.  So what you can do is comment out the action in the content-product.php file:

```
//do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );
```

and then add the below line:

```
?><h3><?php echo apply_filters( 'my_filter_name', get_the_title() ); ?></h3><?php
```

so the saved version looks like this:

```
//do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );
?><h3><?php echo apply_filters( 'my_filter_name', get_the_title() ); ?></h3><?php
```

Then, you would need to add the following to your theme's functions.php file which will pass the contents of get_the_title() to the $title parameter, which you can then change any way you wish, but in the below case will change every title to say "Custom Title":

```
add_filter( 'my_filter_name', 'my_custom_function' );

function my_custom_function( $title ) {
  return 'Custom Title';
}
```

For more information, see the following:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Comment: remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );

Comment: @Chris Excellent! Thank you. Couldn't find a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

in WordPress, you cannot just "overwrite" a hook (that's works only for pluggable functions)

but, you can add new fonction to the same hook and remove an action.

try something like this :

```
add_action("init", function () {
    // removing the woocommerce hook
    remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'change_product_title');
});

// add a new fonction to the hook
add_action("woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title", function () {

    echo "my new action";

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't appear to remove the original title.

Comment: remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );